# Regex in javascript for checking if a variable is either 12 digits or between 6 to 8 digits

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript regex to check if a given number is either 12 digits in length or between 6 to 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/
```

- `^` Matches beginning of string
- `(a|b)` Matches a or b
- `\d{6,8}` Matches between 6-8 digits
- `\d{12}` Matches 12 digits
- `$` Matches end of string

Example matches:

```
"000000000000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
"000000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
"00000000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
```

Example nonmatches:

```
"00000000000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
"00000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
"000000000".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
"00000a00".match(/^(\d{6,8}|\d{12})$/)
```